# target 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0' project dependencies

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

My Visual studio 2017 nuget package can't install following error is occured in Xamarin.Forms Portable class library Project

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Could not install package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 25.3.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.          0

Answer (score 4):

`Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat` version 25.3.1 has dependencies of

- **MonoAndroid 7.0**
- Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations (= 25.3.1)
- Xamarin.Build.Download (>= 0.4.3)

Re: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat/25.3.1

You need to set the `Target Framework` to at least `7.0`.

Re: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/understanding_android_api_levels/#Target_Framework

Comment: @LogeshPalani 2nd link in my answer: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/understanding_android_api_levels/#Target_Framework

Comment: i Accept this answer but there are new error is there

Comment: Error  'Could not install package 'linqtotwitter 4.1.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author'.   0