# Nuget Cant install Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable 27.0.2

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, nuget

I am running into an issue when updating installed Nuget packages in my Xamarin.Android project. When running the updates, I get the following error:

```
Could not install package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable 
27.0.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
'MonoAndroid,Version=v8.0', but the package does not contain any assembly 
references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For 
more information, contact the package author.
```

A quick google search yielded several results with similar answers like the one found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47399204/target-monoandroid-version-v6-0-project-dependencies). It seemed that I simply needed to make sure my `Target Framework` was set high enough.

Following the [instructions found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/android-api-levels?tabs=vswin) I set out to change the `Target Framework` in Visual Studio 2017, however I found that it was already set to use `8.0`.

[image: Target framework already set!]

Is there another step that I am missing in order to get these packages to update?

Comment: API 27 != 8.0. It actually is 8.1. Thus you need Android 8.1 here.

Comment: Make sure VS is up to date

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Jon Douglas mentioned, API 27 actually requires Android 8.1.  If you don't have the option to switch to 8.1 you will need to update Visual Studio. Once that is done, you should be able to install the 8.1 SDK via the Android SDK manager (Tools -> Android -> Android SDK Manager).

[image: Android SDK manager screenshot]

After the SDK is installed, you can set your `Target Framework` to 8.1 and update the Nuget packages.

Comment: Similar problem and I have 8.1 installed.  Also ensured all three Android versions in the project settings are set to 8.1 but error persists.

Answer (score 4):

you have to change your Mono.Android.dll Version to 8.1,
[image: Check here]

Comment: It's not that easy, can you explain how we can update the `Mono.Android` dll?

Answer (score 0):

When I tried updating this library recently, I found there were some old lingering references in the csproj file, causing conflicts.

To resolve,

- Unload the project (right click the project > Unload Project)
- Open the csproj (right click the project > Edit xxx.csproj)
- Remove all references to 'old' targets (for example, the whole reference tag to old libraries)
- There may also be Import tags that need removing

On re-loading the project (right click > Reload Project), I was able to update that library.

Comment: Old references to what?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had Visual Studio 2017 with the most recent SDK version which included Android 8.1.

Even after changing all 3 Android target versions from the project properties to 8.1, the csproj was still showing a TargetFrameworkVersion of 7.1 as follows:

```
  <TargetFrameworkVersion>v7.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

I manually changed that to 8.1

```
 <TargetFrameworkVersion>v8.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

It will be interesting to find out if the minimum Android version still needs to be at 8.1 though.

and was then able to update the Nuget packages.